# How to have multiple versions of app in TestFlight?

Tags: ios, testflight

I've just published an app on Apple's store and I'm wondering about having multiple versions of the same app for testing on TestFlight. Of course dev doesn't stop when publishing... from now on I'll have to update the app store version (**v1.0.0**) with bug fixes (**v1.0.1, v1.0.2, ...**) and before doing so I'd like to check them in test flight to ensure the fix was appropriate.

My problem is that I'm already starting to develop the next version with further functionalities of the app which will become **v1.1**

So ideally I'd like to have my app available both for my bug fixes, for instance **v1.0.2** and also my next version **v1.1.0** (this will include all bug fixes made to the store version and also many new features, refactors, redesign, etc)

I know that if I build and upload to the apple store connect a build with **v1.1.0** (next version) I won't be able to upload one for a built with a bug fix on the current app store version (**v1.0.2**) since this version would be lower than the one I uploaded (next version)

Is there a way to accomplish this? I've read this article https://savvyapps.com/blog/using-testflight-to-distribute-multiple-versions-ios-app which solution is to create extra applications in iTunes with different app ids and bind them to different certificates. But what will happen when the next release is ready to be in the store? I would have to release it and then disable the previous one? How may this affect my users? Will they have to re-install a new app rather than updating it?

I really need to start testing and checking the next release of my app in TestFlight and also support the current one with updates if something pops up. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should increase the version number by each **release** not each *bug fix*.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini not even when following the MAJOR.MINOR.PATH pattern for versioning? It should be possible to split them up... if I increase the version number for a next release to start testing it, then I wouldn't be able to upload another one with a lower version number (which would be meant for a bug fix......)

Comment: No. Just increase it when you released a version. If you didn't release, you may want to increase only the build number. [see here](https://semver.org)

Comment: You can simply have multiple targets in the app one of which points to production and the other pointing to dev. Doing so you will always have the option to keep the versioning on track for the production app and do hotfixes. And along the time the stuff you develop new should be deployed to the dev version of the app and once it is ready for production then the app should be uploaded to the production.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to upload multiple versions of the app to TestFlight. Each upload requires a higher version/build number, but you can switch the TestFlight test version between them as need be for testing.

Once I submit a particular build for release, however, I seem to lose the TestFlight access to the old builds.

In short, you can have many builds available in TestFlight, but once you submit the app for release, you have to start over making builds for TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

You keep talking about numbers like `v1.0.1`. That looks like a public-facing version string, with a major, minor, and patch number.

But that is not what TestFlight cares about. Well, it cares to some extent. But all TestFlight *really* cares about is that every new build you upload has a new *build* number. This is just an integer which you simply increment every time you submit a new build.

So you could have `v1.0.1(23)` on the App Store, and then on TestFlight you could upload `v1.0.2(24)` which starts moving forward toward version 1.0.2, but also upload `v1.0.2(25)` which is actually an attempt at a prospective version 1.1. TestFlight doesn't know or care what these different builds *signify*. They can all exist simultaneously on TestFlight. Keeping them all straight and on their individual trajectories is up to you.